# Updating a TKinter GUI from a multiprocessing calculation

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm creating a `GUI` for a python simulator. The `GUI` provides tools to set up the simulation and run it. While the simulation is running I want to pass progress information to the `GUI` and have it displayed on a `Label` in my `simulation_frame`. Because the simulations need to be run with multiprocessing, I'm using a `Queue` to pass the updated information back to the `GUI`.

The way I have it set up, running the simulations blocks the `Tk` mainloop since I need to be able to close my `Pool` at the end of the call. I'm calling `update_idletasks()` to force the `GUI` to update the progress information.

This seems to me like an inelegant and potentially risky solution. Moreover, while it works in `Ubuntu`, it does not seem to work in `Windows XP`--the window goes blank after a second or so of running. I may be able to make it work in `Windows` by calling `update()` rather than `update_idletasks()`, but that seems even worse to me.

Is there a better solution?

The relevant code:

```
sims = []
queues = []
svars = []
names = []
i = 0
manager = mp.Manager()
for config in self.configs:
    name, file, num = config.get()
    j = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        #progress monitor label
        q = manager.Queue()
        s_var = StringVar()
        label = Label(self.sim_frame, textvariable = s_var, bg = "white")
        s_var.set("%d: Not Started"%i)
        label.grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = W+N)
        self.sim_labels.append(label)
        queues.append(q)
        svars.append(s_var)
        names.append("%s-%d"%(name, j))
        sims.append(("%s-%d"%(name, j),file, data, verbose, q))
        i += 1
        j += 1
self.update()

# The progress tracking is pretty hacky.

pool = mp.Pool(parallel)
num_sims = len(sims)
#start simulating
tracker = pool.map_async(run_1_sim,sims)
while not tracker.ready():
    pass
    for i in range(num_sims):
        q = queues[i]
        try:
            gen = q.get(timeout = .001)
            # if the sim has updated, update the label
            #print gen
            svars[i].set(gen)
            self.update()
        except Empty:
            pass
# The results of the map, if necessary
tracker.get()

    def update(self):
        """
        Redraws everything
        """
        self.master.update_idletasks()

def run_1_sim(args):
    """
    Runs one simulation with the specified args, output updates to the supplied
    pipe every generation
    """
    name,config,data, verbose, q = args
    sim = Simulation(config, name=name, data = data)
    generation = 0
    q.put(sim.name + ": 0")
    try:
        while sim.run(verbose=verbose, log=True, generations = sim_step):
            generation += sim_step
            q.put(sim.name + ": " + str(generation))
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not be helpful to you, but it is possible to make `tkinter` thread-safe by ensuring that its code and methods are executed on the particular thread the root was instantiated on. One project that experimented with the concept can be found over on the [Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) as [recipe 577633](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577633/) (Directory Pruner 2). The code below comes from lines 76 - 253 and is fairly easy to extend with widgets.

---

**Primary Thread-safety Support**

```
# Import several GUI libraries.
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox

# Import other needed modules.
import queue
import _thread
import operator

################################################################################

class AffinityLoop:

    "Restricts code execution to thread that instance was created on."

    __slots__ = '__action', '__thread'

    def __init__(self):
        "Initialize AffinityLoop with job queue and thread identity."
        self.__action = queue.Queue()
        self.__thread = _thread.get_ident()

    def run(self, func, *args, **keywords):
        "Run function on creating thread and return result."
        if _thread.get_ident() == self.__thread:
            self.__run_jobs()
            return func(*args, **keywords)
        else:
            job = self.__Job(func, args, keywords)
            self.__action.put_nowait(job)
            return job.result

    def __run_jobs(self):
        "Run all pending jobs currently in the job queue."
        while not self.__action.empty():
            job = self.__action.get_nowait()
            job.execute()

    ########################################################################

    class __Job:

        "Store information to run a job at a later time."

        __slots__ = ('__func', '__args', '__keywords',
                     '__error', '__mutex', '__value')

        def __init__(self, func, args, keywords):
            "Initialize the job's info and ready for execution."
            self.__func = func
            self.__args = args
            self.__keywords = keywords
            self.__error = False
            self.__mutex = _thread.allocate_lock()
            self.__mutex.acquire()

        def execute(self):
            "Run the job, store any error, and return to sender."
            try:
                self.__value = self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__keywords)
            except Exception as error:
                self.__error = True
                self.__value = error
            self.__mutex.release()

        @property
        def result(self):
            "Return execution result or raise an error."
            self.__mutex.acquire()
            if self.__error:
                raise self.__value
            return self.__value

################################################################################

class _ThreadSafe:

    "Create a thread-safe GUI class for safe cross-threaded calls."

    ROOT = tkinter.Tk

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **keywords):
        "Initialize a thread-safe wrapper around a GUI base class."
        if master is None:
            if self.BASE is not self.ROOT:
                raise ValueError('Widget must have a master!')
            self.__job = AffinityLoop() # Use Affinity() if it does not break.
            self.__schedule(self.__initialize, *args, **keywords)
        else:
            self.master = master
            self.__job = master.__job
            self.__schedule(self.__initialize, master, *args, **keywords)

    def __initialize(self, *args, **keywords):
        "Delegate instance creation to later time if necessary."
        self.__obj = self.BASE(*args, **keywords)

    ########################################################################

    # Provide a framework for delaying method execution when needed.

    def __schedule(self, *args, **keywords):
        "Schedule execution of a method till later if necessary."
        return self.__job.run(self.__run, *args, **keywords)

    @classmethod
    def __run(cls, func, *args, **keywords):
        "Execute the function after converting the arguments."
        args = tuple(cls.unwrap(i) for i in args)
        keywords = dict((k, cls.unwrap(v)) for k, v in keywords.items())
        return func(*args, **keywords)

    @staticmethod
    def unwrap(obj):
        "Unpack inner objects wrapped by _ThreadSafe instances."
        return obj.__obj if isinstance(obj, _ThreadSafe) else obj

    ########################################################################

    # Allow access to and manipulation of wrapped instance's settings.

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        "Get a configuration option from the underlying object."
        return self.__schedule(operator.getitem, self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        "Set a configuration option on the underlying object."
        return self.__schedule(operator.setitem, self, key, value)

    ########################################################################

    # Create attribute proxies for methods and allow their execution.

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        "Create a requested attribute and return cached result."
        attr = self.__Attr(self.__callback, (name,))
        setattr(self, name, attr)
        return attr

    def __callback(self, path, *args, **keywords):
        "Schedule execution of named method from attribute proxy."
        return self.__schedule(self.__method, path, *args, **keywords)

    def __method(self, path, *args, **keywords):
        "Extract a method and run it with the provided arguments."
        method = self.__obj
        for name in path:
            method = getattr(method, name)
        return method(*args, **keywords)

    ########################################################################

    class __Attr:

        "Save an attribute's name and wait for execution."

        __slots__ = '__callback', '__path'

        def __init__(self, callback, path):
            "Initialize proxy with callback and method path."
            self.__callback = callback
            self.__path = path

        def __call__(self, *args, **keywords):
            "Run a known method with the given arguments."
            return self.__callback(self.__path, *args, **keywords)

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            "Generate a proxy object for a sub-attribute."
            if name in {'__func__', '__name__'}:
                # Hack for the "tkinter.__init__.Misc._register" method.
                raise AttributeError('This is not a real method!')
            return self.__class__(self.__callback, self.__path + (name,))

################################################################################

# Provide thread-safe classes to be used from tkinter.

class Tk(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.Tk
class Frame(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Frame
class Button(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Button
class Entry(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Entry
class Progressbar(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar
class Treeview(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Treeview
class Scrollbar(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar
class Sizegrip(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.ttk.Sizegrip
class Menu(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.Menu
class Directory(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.filedialog.Directory
class Message(_ThreadSafe): BASE = tkinter.messagebox.Message
```

---

If you read the rest of the application, you will find that it is built with the widgets defined as `_ThreadSafe` variants that you are used to seeing in other `tkinter` applications. As method calls come in from various threads, they are automatically held until it becomes possible to execute those calls on the creating thread. Note how the `mainloop` is replaced by way of lines 291 - 298 and 326 - 336.

---

**Notice NoDefaltRoot & main_loop Calls**

```
@classmethod
def main(cls):
    "Create an application containing a single TrimDirView widget."
    tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
    root = cls.create_application_root()
    cls.attach_window_icon(root, ICON)
    view = cls.setup_class_instance(root)
    cls.main_loop(root)
```

---

**main_loop Allows Threads To Execute**

```
@staticmethod
def main_loop(root):
    "Process all GUI events according to tkinter's settings."
    target = time.clock()
    while True:
        try:
            root.update()
        except tkinter.TclError:
            break
        target += tkinter._tkinter.getbusywaitinterval() / 1000
        time.sleep(max(target - time.clock(), 0))
```

---

Comment: I think you're right, creating my own "mainloop" is the way to go. That way the whole window updates and I can have such snazzy features as a "Stop" button.

Comment: Came across this looking for ways of making the Tkinter loop cooperative, and if I'm reading that last snippet correctly, I don't think it will work as expected.  The .getbusywaitinterval() seems to return an int ( =20 in my interpreter) and dividing that by 1000 results in int 0.  Therefore, target never increments unless .getbusywaitinterval() returns anything over 1000, which I doubt it normally would.
The fix is easy, just change the 1000 to 1000.0 to perform a float calculation, which will eventually increase the target to be higher than 0, and will actually let the thread sleep.

Comment: I wrote a quick test and found that indeed this always performs a time.sleep(0) with the original code.  Unfortunately, fixing this to perform a proper sleep results in the sleep continually incrementing getting up to 1.5 seconds within a few seconds of execution which makes the application really sluggish.  Leaving with the original bug makes this while loop run very quickly and soaks up quite a bit of processor cycles sitting and waiting for input.  There seems to be no trivial fix.

Comment: @IanE: Directory Pruner 4 (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578154/) uses a much better method of running threads across a GUI. It is part of the evolution of the program that was originally referenced.

Comment: @noctis-skytower That's a much nicer main loop: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578153/
It sleeps for a reasonable time (usually 0.02 seconds on my system on a running program) and is very responsive. Unfortunately for my specific application and possibly others, the self.update() does not return while a user holds a button (OSX/Py2.7). It may work enough for the original question, just note that the UI will likely not be updating while the user manipulates it.