# Tkinter window not playing well with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.3

I've got a program that will eventually receive data from an external source over serial, but I'm trying to develop the display-side first.

I've got this "main" module that has the simulated data send and receive.  It updates a global that is used by a Matplotlib stripchart.  All of this works.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        BBQData
# Purpose:  Gets the data from the Arduino, and runs the threads.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import time
import math
import random
from threading import Thread
import my_globals as bbq
import sys
import BBQStripChart as sc
import serial
import BBQControl as control


ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=10)

def simData():
    newTime = time.time()
    if not hasattr(simData, "lastUpdate"):
        simData.lastUpdate = newTime  # it doesn't exist yet, so initialize it
        simData.firstTime = newTime  # it doesn't exist yet, so initialize it
    if newTime > simData.lastUpdate:
        simData.lastUpdate = newTime
        return (140 + 0.05*(simData.lastUpdate - simData.firstTime), \
            145 + 0.022*(simData.lastUpdate - simData.firstTime), \
            210 + random.randrange(-10, 10))
    else:
        return None

def serialDataPump():
    testCtr = 0;
    while not bbq.closing and testCtr<100:
        newData = simData()
        if  newData != None:
            reportStr = "D " + "".join(['{:3.0f} ' for x in newData]) + '\n'
            reportStr = reportStr.format(*newData)
            ser.write(bytes(reportStr, 'ascii'))
            testCtr+=1
            time.sleep(1)
    bbq.closing = True

def serialDataRcv():
    while not bbq.closing:
        line = ser.readline()
        rcvdTime = time.time()
        temps = str(line, 'ascii').split(" ")
        temps = temps[1:-1]
        for j, x in enumerate(temps):
            bbq.temps[j].append(float(x))
            bbq.plotTimes.append(rcvdTime)

def main():
    sendThread = Thread(target = serialDataPump)
    receiveThread = Thread(target = serialDataRcv)
    sendThread.start()
    receiveThread.start()
#    sc.runUI() 
    control.runControl() #blocks until user closes window
    bbq.closing = True
    time.sleep(2)
    exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
##    testSerMain()
```

However, I'd like to add a SEPARATE tkinter window that just has the most recent data on it, a close button, etc. I can get that window to come up, and show data initially, but none of the other threads run.  (and nothing works when I try to run the window and the plot at the same time.)

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        BBQ Display/Control
# Purpose:      displays current temp data, and control options
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import my_globals as bbq
import threading

fontSize = 78

class BBQControl(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.labelFont = tkinter.font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=int(fontSize*0.8))
        self.dataFont = tkinter.font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=fontSize, weight = 'bold')
        self.makeWindow()


    def makeWindow(self):
        self.grid()

        btnClose = tk.Button(self,text=u"Close")
        btnClose.grid(column=1,row=5)

        lblFood = tk.Label(self,anchor=tk.CENTER, text="Food Temps", \
            font = self.labelFont)
        lblFood.grid(column=0,row=0)
        lblPit = tk.Label(self,anchor=tk.CENTER, text="Pit Temps", \
            font = self.labelFont)
        lblPit.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.food1Temp = tk.StringVar()
        lblFoodTemp1 = tk.Label(self,anchor=tk.E, \
            textvariable=self.food1Temp, font = self.dataFont)
        lblFoodTemp1.grid(column=0,row=1)

        #spawn thread to update temps
        updateThread = threading.Thread(target = self.updateLoop)
        updateThread.start()

    def updateLoop(self):
        self.food1Temp.set(str(bbq.temps[1][-1]))

def runControl():
    app = BBQControl(None)
    app.title('BBQ Display')
    app.after(0, app.updateLoop)
    app.mainloop()
    bbq.closing = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runControl()
```

Comment: Should your `updateLoop` be running in an infinite loop? It seems so, but.... You also shouldn't need `app.after(0, app.updateLoop)` since when you create your `BBQControl` it will start a thread that runs it.

Answer (score 1):

Your title sums up the problem nicely: Tkinter doesn't play well with threads. That's not a question, that's the answer.

You can only access tkinter widgets from the same thread that created the widgets. If you want to use threads, you'll need your non-gui threads to put data on a queue and have the gui thread poll the queue periodically.

Comment: My non-GUI threads update a list that the updateLoop() pulls from.

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting `tkinter` to play well with threads is to modify the library so all method calls run on a single thread. Two other questions deal with this same problem: [Updating a TKinter GUI from a multiprocessing calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540412/updating-a-tkinter-gui-from-a-multiprocessing-calculation/6540833#6540833) and [Python GUI is not responding while thread is executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566751/python-gui-is-not-responding-while-thread-is-executing/13587165#13587165). In turn, the given answers point to several modules that help to solve the problem you are facing. Whenever I work with `tkinter`, I always use the `safetkinter` module in case threads appear to be helpful in the program.